# Get the shadow intensity of the Raycast Hit Point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to project a 3D scene into a 640x480 Raw Image for my assignment. **I have to use Raycasts for this task**. I am using 640x480 Rays and getting the color values of the hit objects and coloring the image accordingly. It partly works but I also need to shadow values to show depth. As you can see in the below image, the green cylinder should have a darker green on the bottom but I couldn't manage to do it.
[image]

My code so far:

```
    const int width = 640;
    const int height = 480;
    [SerializeField] RawImage image;
    void Start()
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(640, 480);
        image.texture = texture;

        for (int i=0;i<width; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                //Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(i,j,0), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.white, 50);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(new Vector3(i,j,0), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
                {
                    texture.SetPixel(i, j, hit.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
                }
            }
        }
        texture.Apply();
       
    }
```

How can I get the relative colors with shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 4 point lights on 4 corners of the room. Then, I cast rays to these point lights from each hit point of the previous raycasts. 4 hits mean the brightest, and no hits mean the darkest. I know this is not an exact solution but it was close enough for my assignment.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last 12 hours working on a similar problem (I needed a way to get how 'well-lit' an object is at runtime, with dynamics lights, and all).

I tried with Raycasts first, and ohhhh did I scratch my head. Looks like you're using Unity, so I'll assume that. Spoiler: I did not end up using raycasts)

What *I think* happens with raycasting is that the rays are cast before some lightning is applied. That's going to cause some problems.

That said, looking at your code, your're only picking the *material* color, which is not going to change depending on your light. Try putting the bottom half of your capsule in another color, maybe you'll be surprized at what happens.

Hope that helps clearing your mind a little bit, and not the opposite!

Best of luck

Comment: Answer could use some code on how you accomplished the similar result.